# why python threading take all my cores

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have written the following multiple threading code in my Ubuntu 14.04

```
import threading

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    while True:
        continue
    return

threads = []
for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
~
```

And here is the image:
      [CPU load image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg29M.png)

One process with four threads, takes four of my CPU cores. Why?

Comment: that's what threading does. What python are you using, with or without GVL?

Comment: This is also a OS level optimization. The OS will try to balance even single threaded applications over several cores (especially Linux) in order to minimize the risk that a single core gets all the havy load. Both for performance reasons but also for "durability" reasons (even tho little focus on the later)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i am using Cython, with GIL.

Comment: @Torxed o, make sense, here i hope even though with four thread tasks, should only take one core, and the other cores will be idle. it should time sharing the one core for four tasks.

Comment: Voted to close as this seems to be a question about what threads are and how they work in general, not a question about a specific programming problem.